# How fast can the Shinkansen N700 train take a curve?

Tags: rail, highway-engineering

As a transit advocate, I'm evaluating an urban freeway corridor for high-speed rail. Given the geometry of the existing highway, the track alignment will be a compromise between train speed and right-of-way acquisition for curve straightening. To inform my alignment choice, I'd like to know how fast the train can travel through a curve of given radius.

For example, when I was looking on Google Earth I found:

- a 450 meter radius curve due south of Shinagawa station.
- a 1000 meter radius curve due west of Shin-Osaka station.

How fast can the Shinkansen N700 series travel through these curves? Is there a table I can reference? Or perhaps a recording of a Shinkansen trip that includes a readout of speed?

Comment: The manufacturer may have some info.

Comment: Don't forget to factor in "superelevation", the banking of the track, to eliminate / reduce the wheel-rail flange contact. This will be a major factor in curve speed limit.

Comment: @Transistor  yep, ultimately the limits are more or less based on the maximum g-force passengers will put up with, and, more important,  the maximum bank angle for which the train won't tip over if forced to come to a stop.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I don't understand why I'm getting downvoted; is there something wrong with my engineering question?